# redirect too many times in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

when i enter my /home route then show this  problem **redirect page too many times**.
I created a custom middleware this name UserRole.In this middleware I have put a condition if role==1 then go to root(/) route otherwise it go to /home route.First condition worked properly but else condition  throw this problem **redirect page too many times**.
My code is given below:

```
web.php
Route::get('/', 'FrontendController@FrontPage');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@dashboard');

Kernel.php

'user_role' => \App\Http\Middleware\UserRole::class,


UserRole.php(midleware)

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::user()->role == 1){
        return redirect('/');
    }
    else{
        return redirect('/home');
    }
}

Homecontroller.php
  class HomeController extends Controller
 {

 public function __construct()
  {
    $this->middleware('user_role');
  }

 public function dashboard()
  {
    return view('backend.dashboard');
  }
 }

FrontendController.php

class FrontendController extends Controller
{
public function FrontPage(){
    $products=Product::all();
    return view('frontend.main',compact('products'));
}
public function shopPage(){
    $categories=Category::orderBy('name','asc')->get();
    $title='All Product';
    return view('frontend.shop',compact('categories','title'));
 }
}
```

Comment: Why did you use middleware to handle this? Are you using laravel auth scaffolding?

Answer (score 3):

You have an infinite loop.
When you enter in HomeController you pass by the middleware. This middleware redirect you to the HomeController, the controller call the middleware....

You can change the middleware like this

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::user()->role == 1){
        return redirect('/');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

This middleware check if you're role is 1.
If it's true go to '/'
If not continue

Comment: `return $next($request);`

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer.Now it is working properly.